# Using Lightroom 3, is it possible to upload photos to Flickr so that the flickr sets reflect the Lightroom Collections automatically?

Tags: adobe-lightroom, flickr

I usually use the built-in Flickr publisher in Lightroom to publish photos to Flickr.

This is good as it'll automatically persist tags and names and descriptions and general metadata.

However, ideally I'd like to put my have my Lightroom photos in collection, and then drop them into the Flickr Publisher, and have the collections created or updated as sets.

Is this possible?

If not, is the same possible for the Hard Driver publisher?

Essentially, *I want my Lightroom collections to automatically be exported somehow out of Lightroom*.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to *automatically* export collections short of you initiating the action yourself (e.g., clicking "Publish" on the built-in Flickr publisher). You might be able to write or find a plugin that would do this for you, but I don't know of any offhand.

Comment: thanks kerri... yeah, seems like an obvious feature! especially for the harddriver publishing

Comment: @andy Totally agree; I wish they had the feature as well. Then I wouldn't have to go through each folder and publish manually. Here's hoping for it in a future release...